# Is this the correct way to write unit test for Interactor in VIPER, swift, iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, viper-architecture

I have a small sorting function in the `Interactor` which takes a set of `String`s and sort it and notify to the `Presenter`. That function works as expected.

Now I'm just trying cover that function **with unit test**. so I created a `Unit Test Class` for my `Interactor` and `Mocked` the `Interactor Output` and did the test like below. **am I doing it right?**

[image: screen shot of unit-test source code]

> shouldn't we end the test inside the `testFunction`, in this case
> inside the `testSortFunction()`

This triggers `notifySortedNames()` in the `Mock Interactor Output Class` and I tested the use case inside that. I guess this is the wrong way.

**How can I achieve the testing of this scenario inside the `testFunction()`? I'd appreciate your help with this.**

**Interactor**

```
class DetailInteractor: DetailInteractorInput {
    var output: DetailInteractorOutput?
    
    init(output: DetailInteractorOutput) {
        self.output = output
    }
    
    func sortNames(names: [String]) {
        
        let sorteNames = names.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
        output?.notifySortedNames(names: sorteNames)
    }
}
```

**Interactor Test Class**

```
import XCTest
@testable import UnitTesst

class DetailInteractorTest: XCTestCase {
    
    var interactor: DetailInteractor!
    var output: DetailInteractorOutput!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
       
        output = DetailInteractorOutputMock()
        interactor = DetailInteractor(output: output)
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        
    }

    func testSortFunction() throws {
        
        let names = ["Japan", "France", "Australia"]
        interactor.sortNames(names: names)
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() throws {
        
        self.measure {
            
        }
    }
}

// Mock Test Classes
class DetailInteractorOutputMock: DetailInteractorOutput {
    
    func notifySortedNames(names: [String]) {
        
        let expected = ["Australia", "France", "Japan"]
        XCTAssertEqual(expected[0], names[0])
        XCTAssertEqual(expected[1], names[1])
        XCTAssertEqual(expected[2], names[2])
    }
}
```

**Thanks!!**

Comment: Please explain how you know “I guess this is the wrong way.”  Is your test case giving false positives or false negatives or crashing or so forth?  Did this test's source code fail a code review?